# aws ec2 uWSGI ""hello world"" error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx

I launched new aws ec2 instance.
My goal is deploying django project.

I want to construct nginx proxy server and uWSGI Web server.
I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-uwsgi-and-nginx-to-serve-python-apps-on-ubuntu-14-04) step by step.

However, absurdly I got error in first hello world example.

I installed basic development environment.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
$ echo "export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3"
$ echo "export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ mkdir ~/Practice1 && cd ~/Practice1
$ mkvirtualenv MY_ENV1
(MY_ENV1)$ pip install uwsgi
(MY_ENV1)$ vim test.py

#test.py    
def application(env, start_response):
        start_response("200 OK", [('Content-Type','text/html')])
        return [b"Hello World!"]
```

`(MY_ENV1)$ uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file test.py`

I can't connect my IP **xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8000** in web browser.

**xxx.xx.xxx.xx** also can't connect.

**P.S)** below is my instance Security Group setting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) I am not certain that gunicorn will bind to all interfaces by default. Could you try modifying your command to the following?

```
uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:8000 --wsgi-file test.py
```

2) Your security group is not allowing access to port 8000. You must allow access to port 8000 if you want to hit it externally.

Comment: 1) 0.0.0.0:8000 still I disconnected.

2) When I select Type **HTTP**, then Protocol TCP & Port Range 80 is enforced. I can't change those value.

Which one should I choose??

Comment: @newbie16 set type to `TCP` and set port to `8000`. Don't use `HTTP` - it's a known port protocol so it's always going to be `80` in AWS Security Groups. Same if you pick other known protocols like `SSH` or `RDP`.

Comment: I'm sorry i am late for reply. Umm It is still error.... 
I selected type custom TCP Rule and port range 8000.
what's wrong with me??

Comment: @newbie16 if you run it as you do, what happens if you try to it it locally with something like `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000`?

Comment: @birryree I got this message.
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000: Connection refused`
Wait, should I also create load balancer, target group?? I only created security group.

Comment: @newbie16 if you're getting that message on the UWSGI server itself, then your application isn't running. Also, don't need a load balancer. But there are other details that you probably need to tell us, like: is your server in a public subnet or a private subnet?

Comment: how can I check whether my server in a public subnet or private subnet?

Comment: @newbie16 - look at your Virtual Private Cloud design. Is your instance in a subnet accesses the internet via an `igw` (Internet gateway) or a NAT instance?

Comment: It seems that my instance in a subnet.
my instance has **VPC ID** and **Subnet ID**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154386/discussion-between-newbie16-and-birryree).